# MySQL "day" - how do I get an exact figure?

Tags: mysql

I am using this function to filter query results that are older than 60 days:

```
s.timeSubmitted >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY )
```

The problem is, the "60 days" part doesn't seem to be an exact figure.  I want it to filter right where s.timeSubmitted is longer than 60 days, down to the exact second of s.timeSubmitted.

How do I write "60 Days" as an exact figure (down to the second)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) returns a [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) type, not a [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) type (an instant in time). The result of subtracting an interval from a `DATE` is *also* a `DATE`.
Instead, try this:

```
s.timeSubmitted >= ( NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY )
```

This gives you what you want, because [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) returns a `DATETIME`, so the result of the subtraction is also a `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 3):

`INTERVAL 60 DAY` *is* exact - your problem is that `CURDATE()` isn't.  It returns whole days, not the current time.

Use `NOW()` instead!

Comment: `CURDATE` is just `DATE(NOW())`. There's no difference between them ,except curdate doesn't include the hh:mm:ss portion.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do

```
now()-interval 60 day
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the same time of day 60 days ago;

```
s.timeSubmitted >= ( now() - interval 60 day);
```

Maybe an un-necessary note in this case; 1 day ago may be 23, 24 or 25 hours ago depending on DST changes, if you want a specific number of hours as an interval, don't use a day instead of 24 hours.